# Ubuntu 16.04: Unity loads, but launcher/panel won't

Tags: ubuntu, unity-game-engine

Somewhere after toying around in `unity-tweak-tool` and installing VMware Player (which crashed when the screensaver started, and got this whole mess rolling), I'm stuck without a panel or launcher. I've done all the usual `dconf` reset procedures, cleared caches, etc, and I now log in, can right click, open a terminal, and use that to run applications. I have also run `apt-get install --reinstall` on unity, ubuntu-desktop and all compiz components. The window manager is running, but just not the rest.

Also just noticed - if I open `ccsm` then Unity is not enabled. Turning it on causes this flashing on/off of every window, as they cascade towards the bottom-right corner of the screen. Following this, I can only seem to get back to where I started by running `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

Suggestions to try?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0):

At login time, use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to access the command line interface. 
Just use your username and password here. 
Once logged in, use the following commands:

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 sudo apt-get install unity
 sudo shutdown -r now`